# Are there rules and ethics to follow in space?

Tags: nasa, law

If someone were to go to the moon and set up their own camp. Would NASA and governments be okay with it? Or would they not care?

Is there a rule that says I can't do anything to the moon or else people will put me in prison or something?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty is gonna be a big part of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Liability_Convention if you screw up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly dependent on who the parties in question answer to. Also rules, ethics, and laws are three quite different (though sometimes related) things.  To address the *ethics* part of the question, here are a few examples.

There is a [Code of Conduct for ISS Crewmembers](http://www.esa.int/esapub/bulletin/bullet105/bul105_6.pdf).

> ...the  Code has  been  implemented  in  Europe  through  a directive
>   of the ESA Director General addressed individually   to   members   of
>   the   European Astronaut  Corps  (EAC),  in  which  they  are invited 
>   to  agree  in  writing  to  the  terms  and conditions  in  the  Code,
>   a  process  that  is consistent  with  the  ESA  Staff  Regulations 
>   and the  decision  taken  in  March  1998  by  the  ESA Council  on 
>   the  modalities  for  building  up  the EAC. In  the  United  States,  the  Code  has  become
>   part of the US astronauts’ terms and conditions
>   of   employment   through   the   adoption   on  1  October  2000  of  corresponding  regulations
>   under NASA’s existing legislation (14 CFR Part 214). In Japan, the Code will be incorporated
>   into regulations consistent with the terms of the
>   legislation  that  established  the  National  Space
>   Development  Agency  (NASDA)  and  Japanese
>   astronauts,  as  employees  of  NASDA,  will  be
>   invited  to  sign  up  to  the  terms  of  the  Code.
>   Similarly  in  Russia,  the  cosmonauts  will  be
>   invited to sign up individually to the terms of the
>   Code  once  it  becomes  part  of  the  regulations
>   and policies applicable to the Russian Aviation
>   and  Space  Agency  (RSA).  In  Canada,  where
>   astronauts  are  appointed  by  decision  of  the
>   Cabinet, the Code will become part of the terms
>   and  conditions  of  astronauts’  employment  in the  same  manner,  i.e.  through  an  Order in Council issued by the Cabinet.

And a [NASA Astronaut Code of Professional Responsibility.](https://www.jsc.nasa.gov/Bios/AstronautCodeEarthFINAL.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Great answer! You might add a link to the Moon Treaty, which prohibits nations from claiming land on the moon.

Comment: @barrycarter Notably,the Moon Treaty is not ratified by any of the countries most likely to be able to colonize or exploit the Moon.